# How to calculate the average number of words in turns in conversation

Tags: r, calculation

I'd like to calculate in a clean fashion the average number of words in a speaking turn in conversation based on the following premises:

The average number of syllables in a turn is 11. Obviously, not all words in English conversation are one syllable long, some may be two or three or more syllables long; so the average number of *words* must be smaller than 11. The proportions of n-syllabic words in speaking turns are given in dataframe `df_syll`:

```
df_syll <- data.frame(
  n_syll = 1:6,
  ave_prop_turn = c(0.8093095, 0.1452075, 0.02380278, 0.004130556, 0.0007833333, 1e-04)
)
```

Thus, for example, the proportion of one-syllabic words is quite high with 0.8093095, the respective proportion of two-syllabic words is 0.1452075, and so forth.

Based on these premises, what is the average number of *words* in a speaking turn?

Comment: Interesting question.  Seems like it belongs to mathematics purely and not SO

Comment: Assume that there are, on average, _x_ words in a speaking turn. Based on your premises, in a speaking turn, there must be _0.8093095x_ one-syllabic words, _0.1452975x_ two-syllabic words, and so on and so forth. Hence, on average, _0.8093095x*1+0.1452975x*2+...+1e-04x*6=11_ syllables exist in a turn. Solve this equation and you have the answer.

Comment: That's I guess it, right?: `11/sum(df_syll$ave_prop_turn*df_syll$n_syll)
[1] 9.226859`

Comment: Yup, I think so @ChrisRuehlemann

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann instead of using sum use scalar product `11/(ave_prop_turn %*% 1:6)`